Mutation and isoform data files don't have the right structure for R manipulation and I don't know how to fix it
The problem
I need to analyze some data about mutations and isoforms. Specifically the enrichment of mutations across isoforms.

I have included the minimal reproducible example code and the first 10 lines of the mutation information I'm parsing.

I got the mutation data from clinvar: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=aire%5Bgene%5D&redir=gene
with the some restricting criteria for including only high pathogenicity and only missense variants

The problem is that I don't know where I can find documentation that tells me how to tell R to use mutation and isoform information and plot their connection.

What I tried
I searched for aire[gene] on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar and checked likely pathogenic, pathogenic, missense and single nucleotype on the left to limit my results for the first download.
I tried using this data in the following code:
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(Biostrings)

# Load mutation data from "AIRE_mutation_data.txt"
mutations <- read.table("AIRE_mutation_data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

# Convert the data to a data frame
mutations_df <- data.frame(mutations)

# Convert the "variant" column to a factor
mutations_df$variant <- factor(mutations_df$variant)

but I get an error saying:

Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, variant, value = integer(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 21
Calls: $<- -> $<-.data.frame

in addition to some errors talking about object package masking.
The first 10 lines of the AIRE_mutation_data.txt file are:
Name    Gene(s) Protein change  Condition(s)    Accession   GRCh37ChromosomGRCh37Location   GRCh38Chromosome    GRCh38Location  VariationID AlleleID(s) dbSNP ID    Canonical SPDI  Variant type    Molecular consequence   Germline classification Germline date last evaluated    Germline review status  Somatic clinical impact Somatic clinical impact date last evaluated Somatic clinical impact review status   Oncogenicity classification Oncogenicity date last evaluated    Oncogenicity review status  
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.1A>G (p.Met1Val)    AIRE    M1V Inherited Immunodeficiency Diseases|Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV000551136    21  45705890    21  44286007    551136  549127  rs121434258 NC_000021.9:44286006:A:G    single nucleotide variant   missense variant|initiator_codon_variant    Pathogenic/Likely pathogenic    May 21, 2021    criteria provided, multiple submitters, no conflicts                        
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.1A>T (p.Met1Leu)    AIRE    M1L not provided|Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1  VCV000003314    21  45705890    21  44286007    3314    18353   rs121434258 NC_000021.9:44286006:A:T    single nucleotide variant   missense variant|initiator_codon_variant    Pathogenic  Aug 16, 2023    criteria provided, multiple submitters, no conflicts    
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.2T>C (p.Met1Thr)    AIRE    M1T Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV002138396    21  45705891    21  44286002138396  1868551     NC_000021.9:44286007:T:C    single nucleotide variant   missense variant|initiator_codon_variant    Pathogenic  Aug 5, 2022 criteria provided, single submitter                 
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.2T>G (p.Met1Arg)    AIRE    M1R Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV001451244    21  45705891    21  44286001451244  1429498 rs2146374989    NC_000021.9:44286007:T:G    single nucleotide variant   missense variant|initiator_codon_variant    Pathogenic  Jan 11, 2022    criteria provided, single submitter             
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.2T>A (p.Met1Lys)    AIRE    M1K Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV001322985    21  45705891    21  44286001322985  1313278 rs2146374989    NC_000021.9:44286007:T:A    single nucleotide variant   missense variant|initiator_codon_variant    Pathogenic  Jul 26, 2021    criteria provided, single submitter             
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.44G>A (p.Arg15His)  AIRE    R15H    Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV000992986    21  45705933    21  4428605992986   980969  rs179363876 NC_000021.9:44286049:G:A    single nucleotide variant   missense variant    Pathogenic  Mar 25, 2024    criteria provided, single submitter                         
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.44G>T (p.Arg15Leu)  AIRE    R15L    Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV000068226    21  45705933    21  442860568226    79117   rs179363876 NC_000021.9:44286049:G:T    single nucleotide variant   missense variant    Pathogenic  Jan 4, 2024 criteria provided, single submitter                         
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.47C>T (p.Thr16Met)  AIRE    T16M    Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV000068227    21  45705936    21  442860568227    79118   rs179363877 NC_000021.9:44286052:C:T    single nucleotide variant   missense variant    Pathogenic  Jan 2, 2024 criteria provided, multiple submitters, no conflicts                    
NM_000383.4(AIRE):c.62C>T (p.Ala21Val)  AIRE    A21V    Polyglandular autoimmune syndrome, type 1   VCV000068228    21  45705951    21  442860668228    79119   rs179363886 NC_000021.9:44286067:C:T    single nucleotide variant   missense variant    Pathogenic/Likely pathogenic    Jan 23, 2024    criteria provided, multiple submitters, no conflicts


Hello to stockoverflow, Quasar. You will find a lot of friends here when you provide a so-called minimal reproducible example and then explain what does not work (as expected) or what you tried so far to fix your problem. I am not in your field and you lost me already in your description. Can you break down your problem? Is the first data set you are downloading/preparing or the 2nd breaking the code?
You are new, so let's not make this too complex. Take the first 10 lines of both files and add the output of dput() here.
Could you also highlight where/which part of the code breaks?

Which line of code generates your error?  As @Ray writes, all of us (even those familiar with the techniques you are using) will need some test data if we are accurately to diagnose and solve your problem.

Yes, thanks for giving advice for editing the post. I'll add in the minimal amount of code that gives the error and the files I am parsing in the original post :)

OK, Quasar, this gets us going. When you read in your data, check what you have. For the data.frame, names(mutations_df) will give you the column names (or variable names) of your dataset. Here you will see that there is no variable variant. Ergo, when you want to coerce the non-existing variable (or column) to be a factor, the code fails with the -- I agree difficult to decipher - error message. Checking your dataset, there appears to be a Variant type. If this is the column you are interested, you can change its name to variant to make the factor() call work.

I quite literally started learning R last tuesday. I got home from my summer research job for the weekend and the overwhelming information annoyed me. After not thinking about it the last 2 days I am no longer annoyed. I must admit I just asked perplexity AI to write some code for me to try to see results. I understand now how not checking the column name made the error. I still have some learning to do before I can use ggplot on the information but I am eternally grateful for your patience!
